# Why are certain 3rd party modules not saving admin settings properly?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

There are two modules that I have documented where admin settings not get saved in my Drupal 6 installation. Specifically I am talking about logintoboggan and Service Links modules. When I make admin changes and hit save and then hit refresh later on: all my settings revert back.

Why?

I also found out that the same code base works fine on my local dev however does not work on the server. Only difference I can think of is I have MYSQL and on server they have MYSQLi. That should not make a difference in my opinion. Other difference I just found out is that my local dev does not have memcache while the server does. I did notice that the modules in question use a lot of variable_get and variable_set. Again these are just 2 modules I have noticed doing that.

Narrowed it further down in sense that I almost want to say that variable_get() is not working properly. Even though I am seeing valid data in the variable table, variable_get is not pulling it out properly.

Another finding: ok so in one of the modules there is a variable_get that is pulling either the correct setting (toboggan/denied) or (node/200) even though the {variable} table is set to toboggan/denied? 
 where is the node/200 coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you are caching variable_get in the memcache, but aren't invalidating the cached results properly. I would take a look at how you have setup your caching.

Comment: can you give a small example since I am not that familiar with Drupal/memCache setups. Thanks

Comment: ok so in one of the modules there is a variable_get that is pulling either the correct setting (toboggan/denied) or (node/200) even though the {variable} table is set to toboggan/denied? 
 where is the node/200 coming from ?